# When using AWS Cognito on Android, is there a way to automatically sign a user in after signup?

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My Android app uses AWS Cognito (v1) for signup and sign-in, both with two-factor authentication (2FA).

After the user signs up, the result of `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()` indicates that the user is not signed in. As a result, the user must sign in (with a second 2FA token) immediately after signing up, which isn't ideal from a UX perspective.

The JavaScript API seems to provide an `autoSignIn` option for this very use case: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-up.

Is there a way to do something similar on Android?